# Hibernate Query returns duplicate result set when using H2 and HSQL DB

Tags: java, hibernate, h2, hsqldb

i'm working on a desktop app and i need to use an embedded database however a particular query in hibernate return a duplicated result set when i'm using HSQL or H2 database but it work fine using Mysql

This is the HQL

```
session.createQuery("SELECT tr FROM Record r INNER JOIN r.trackers  tr WHERE r.id = :id AND tr.product = :product");
```

Comment: Check data in the tables :-). If you are running it in a loop then you can set show_sql flag to true.  Also, execute the same query using EXPLAIN PLAN.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks wrong. Perhaps it is not the full query you are running. You need to specify the columns used for joining the two tables. I have added pseudo-code inside < > markers.

```
SELECT <the columns> FROM Record r INNER JOIN trackers tr 
<ON (r.joincolumn = tr.joincolumn)> 
WHERE r.id = :id AND tr.product = :product
```